# It should be coming up here

Tags: meaning-in-context, verbs, phrasal-verbs

In the TV show "*The Leftovers*" a family bough a house at an auction. The circumstances surrounding this purchase resulted in them no knowing what the house really looks like or where exactly it is located. They are driving in a car and the femal companion is holding a folder in her hand (presumably with a map inside) and she says to her male companion (who is driving) while looking out the window from the passanger seat:

"*It should be coming up here* (the house) *on the right in just a sec.*"

Does "*come up*" in this context mean something to the tune of "*appear*" like in this definition...

Arise, present itself, as in *This question never came up.*
(The American Heritage® Dictionary of Idioms by Christine Ammer. Copyright © 2003, 1997 by The Christine Ammer 1992 Trust)

​...? Or, in it isn't an the idiom "*come up*" but the verb "*come*" which means...

To move into view; appear: *The moon came over the horizon.*

...followed by "*up here*" which means essentailly the same thing as "*here*"?

Comment: Yes, if something appears we can say it 'comes up'.

Comment: Both, I would think. Obviously it's the car that is moving, not the house, but as they approach the house it will appear to 'move into view'.

Comment: **When you are driving** (in a vehicle), *come up*  means a building or place will soon be seen out the window by people in the car. It is the same as the more formal: come into view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's best to treat "coming up" as a phrase in this sentence rather than "up here." ("Up here" can certainly also be a phrase as in "the house is just up here.") And yes, the definitions you found of "arise/appear" work well. By using the progressive "coming," there's also an added sense; "coming up" can sometimes be interchangeable with "upcoming" to express the near future, like when TV channels say "You're watching the Flintstones. Coming up next, the Jetsons!" So I'd say that "It should be coming up here on the right in a sec" blends these meanings to express "It should be appearing very soon, on the right." As for "here," it's just sort of a filler word, but it helps to contribute to this sense of immediacy and the present. The sentence could have had the same meaning without it, but we see it in this context of giving verbal directions to convey a vague sense of the immediacy of the next step, as in "You're gonna turn left here after this curve" (rather than "turn left *soon*," which might be in as much as a few minutes). The "here" suggests that we're close enough to the thing being discussed that it's part of our frame of reference; we might use it when the thing we're discussing is actually within sight, or (as in this case) nearly so.